# How can I create a new line in a Visualforce CSV without using Apex code?

Tags: visualforce

Normally, I'd be iterating over a collection of records, but to simplify it I just have a header and two rows hard-coded, so that I could easily test it.

```
<apex:page 
       readOnly="true"
       contentType="application/octet-stream#MyCsv.csv"
       sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       showHeader="false"
       cache="true"
       expires="0">

    <apex:outputText value="Column 1,Column 2,Column 3"/>  <!-- what to put here ?-->
    <apex:outputText value="aVal1,aVal2,aVal3"/> <!-- ...and here? -->
    <apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>

</apex:page>
```

It works if I use a controller property and reference it as follows, but I'd rather not put that new line in the controller.

```
public String getNewLine() {
    return '\n';
}

<apex:outputText value="{!newLine}"/>
```

I've tried `apex:outputText value="\n"`, `\r`, `\r\n`, `BR()`, `<br/>`, `&#010;`,`&#012;`,`&#013;`, also with each using `escape="false"` but nothing seems to work 100% correctly.  Tried outputting all of the above in the `value` of the outputText and also on their own (i.e., not in an `apex:outputText`).  Still couldn't work.

One thing that I did notice was that if I put the \n at the beginning of the line it does create a new line in the CSV, but literal \n also appears in the file:

```
\n<apex:outputText value="aVal1,aVal2,aVal3"/>
```

does output on a new line, but the output includes the literal '\n':

```
\naVal1,aVal2,aVal3
```

If it matters, using Windows and Excel to open the CSV.

Comment: Have you tried \r\n at the end of each line?

Comment: Yes, I did. Updated the question.

Comment: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Visualforce-Excel-and-line-breaks/td-p/184151

Comment: Wow, very odd. I can't seem to find a clean way of doing this, at all. I think the best way, is to use Apex, but, after experimenting there may be one extremely hacky way to achieve this. Based on your example of \n at the beginning of the line forcing newLines, but also outputting the literal value, I tried a couple of things. &nbsp; at the beginning will force a newline, but also include a space in the first column, I couldn't find a way around this, so I just added a rowCount column, to force this newline. Example: https://gist.github.com/4137588

Comment: @Mikey you should post that as an answer, it will get my upvote

Comment: @DanielBlackhall Just did. I didn't like it as an answer at first, because I don't think it fully answers the question...but after a few days with no activity, it may be the closet thing.

Comment: Are you set on the csv format? I know if you use contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#MyCsv.xls" it'll take \n as a new line without keeping the literal value.

Answer (score 9):

```
<apex:variable value="" var="newline"/>
<apex:outputText value="Column 1,Column 2,Column 3"/>  <!-- what to put here ?-->
{!newline}<apex:outputText value="aVal1,aVal2,aVal3"/> <!-- ...and here? -->
{!newline}<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>
```

Comment: Works, but *why* does it work!?

Answer (score 3):

With no other answers posted, I'm afraid this may be the best that you're able to achieve.

There doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing this.  I think the best way, is to use Apex, but, after experimenting there may be one extremely hacky way to achieve this. Based on your example of \n at the beginning of the line forcing newLines, but also outputting the literal value, I tried a couple of things. First, &nbsp; at the beginning will force a newline, but also include a space in the first column, I couldn't find a way around this, so I just added a rowCount column, to force this newline.

```
<apex:page readOnly="true"
       contentType="application/octet-stream#MyCsv.csv"
       sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       showHeader="false"
       cache="true"
       expires="0">


<!--
This will create a newLine, but will insert an empty space in the first column of every row.

<apex:outputText value="Column 1,Column 2,Column 3"/>
&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="aVal1,aVal2,aVal3"/>
&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>
&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>
&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>
&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/>
-->

<!--
Use a dummy "rowCount" column to still force a newline, but preserve the actual value (e.g., no uneccessary space)
and attempt to not lose too much value by having a somewhat not-useless column (debatable)
-->
<apex:variable value="{!1}" var="rowNum"/>
<apex:outputText value="Row,Column 1,Column 2,Column 3"/>
{!rowNum},<apex:outputText value="aVal1,aVal2,aVal3"/><apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
{!rowNum},<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/><apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
{!rowNum},<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/><apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
{!rowNum},<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/><apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
{!rowNum},<apex:outputText value="bVal1,bVal2,bVal3"/><apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  I'm thinking it might be necessary to use XSLT.

Comment: The best I found was adding a '\n' to the beginning of the first column of each row.

Answer (score 0):

You don't required to use apex only for new line in csv. If you Press enter after writing code for first row, 2nd row will come in new line automatically.
Try code below as it is, you will understand.

```
<apex:page readOnly="true"
       contentType="application/octet-stream#MyCsv.csv"
       sidebar="false"
       standardStylesheets="false"
       showHeader="false"
       cache="true"
       expires="0">
<br/>value1ForRow1, value2ForRow1<br/>
value1ForRow2, value2ForRow2<br/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: True, but not what the question is asking.  Issue is that if value1ForRow1 is outputted from a apex tag, it doesn't register as a new line as you'd expect in this case (since in most cases you wouldn't expect a tag being on a separate line implies a new line).

Comment: Ok! Now try to put '"\n"' before apex:outputText.                            public String getNewLine() {
    return '"\n"';
}

<apex:outputText value="{!newLine}"/>

Comment: The newLine method worked for me. Also have to reduce all of the white space in the VF page, all of it, in order to get rid of the unnecessary carriage returns at the first row, etc. I have also used a tableExporter script in the past but for this client was trying to keep it simple: https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was not to use `<apex:outputText>`, try the below:

```
<apex:page 
 readOnly="true"
 contentType="application/octet-stream#MyCsv.csv"
 sidebar="false"
 standardStylesheets="false"
 showHeader="false"
 cache="true"
 expires="0"><!--  
-->Column 1,Column 2,Column 3
aVal1,aVal2,aVal3
bVal1,bVal2,bVal3<!--
--></apex:page>
```