# How to add break line in export text file

Tags: apex, visualforce

i All,
      I trying to download program for contact object , the user click the "Download" custom button it should download all the records from the  object. This download file should in text format(.txt).when i download a file it display like this
johnkumarjane but i want to display like this in text file

```
john  
kumar
jane
```

how to add break line

`<apex:page Controller="contactquery" contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt"  cache="true">
<apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="contact">
<apex:outputText value="{!contact.Name}" escape="false"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!contact.Id}" escape="false"/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>`
public class contactquery{

```
public List<Contact> cs{get; set;}
public string empId;
public contactquery() 
{
cs = new List<Contact>();
   for (Contact c : [Select id, Name from Contact ])
   {           
       cs.add(c);          

   }

}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the use of the apex:outputtext component that causes everything to remain on the same line.  If you simply use the merge fields, the line breaks work as expected. E.g.

```
<apex:page Controller="ContactQuery" contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt" cache="true"> 
   <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="contact"> 
  {!contact.Name} {!contact.Id} 
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Opening the output file in vi, shows the following - the line numbers indicate that each entry is on a new line:

[image]

Elsewhere you have indicated that you are using notepad to open the output file - the problem here is that notepad expects each line to contain a carriage return followed by a line feed, whereas the text file simply contains a line feed.  You can handle this server side by building a string that contains the contact elements you are interested in plus the carriage return line feed characters.

Revised controller (updated to include fixed size name):

```
public class ContactQuery{

    public List<String> contstr {get; set;}
    public string empId;
    public contactquery() 
    {
       contStr=new List<String>();
       for (Contact c : [Select id, Name from Contact ])
       {               
           String nameStr=c.Name.rightPad(40);
           contStr.add(nameStr  + ' ' + c.Id + '\r');
       }

    }      
}
```

Revised page:

```
<apex:page Controller="ContactQuery" contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt" cache="true"> 
   <apex:repeat value="{!contstr}" var="str"> 
    {!str} 
  </apex:repeat> 
</apex:page>
```

Opening the output from this page in vi shows that there is a carriage return at the end of the line (the ^M character), followed by a line feed, and each name is padded to 40 characters:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It working correctly, have changed the code for (Contact c : [Select Name,Phone,Email,Fax from Contact ]) { cs.add(c.Name.rightPad(40)+ c.Email.rightPad(30)+ c.Phone.rightPad(20)+c.Fax.rightPad(20) + '\r'); }